# CLOS: What I am doing here, setting a slot in the metaclass?

Tags: common-lisp, clos

```
(ql:quickload :postmodern)
(defpackage :test-case
  (:use :cl)
  (:import :pomo))
(in-package :test-case)

;; (defclass dao-class (standard-class)
;;   ((direct-keys :initarg :keys :initform nil :reader direct-keys)
;;    (effective-keys :reader dao-keys)
;;    (table-name)
;;    (column-map :reader dao-column-map))
;;   (:documentation "Metaclass for database-access-object classes."))

(defclass definition ()
  ((id :col-type serial :reader definition-id)
   (content :col-type string :initarg :content :accessor definition-content)
   (word :col-type string :initarg :word :accessor definition-word))
  (:metaclass dao-class)
  (:keys id))

(pomo:dao-keys 'definition)
;; => (ID)
;; What I am setting with :keys? a slot in the meta class?
```

https://gist.github.com/PuercoPop/5850773

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dao-class` has the slot `direct-keys`, whose `:initarg` is named `:keys`, so, if I understand your question correctly, the answer ist: "Yes, `(:keys id)` provides the value for the `direct-keys` slot in the meta-class `dao-class`."

**EDIT** To be more precise, here, since the wording is not quite clear... `dao-class` is a meta-class, i.e., a class, whose instances are classes themselves. In this case, the **class** `definition` is an **instance** of `dao-class`, which has the slot `direct-keys` (declared in `dao-class`), and the value of that slot in `definition` is initialized from the value supplied via the `:keys` option.